# Chrome Extension: Check if iframe and current page has loaded

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-script

I've built an extension that loads a React-application via an iframe. 
I'm passing a message from the application and listening for that message in content script to ensure application has loaded.
Here's a simplified version of what I have so far:

**App.js**

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.top.postMessage({isAppLoaded: true}, '*'};
}
```

**Content.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender) {
    if (msg.isPageLoaded) {
        console.log('Current page has loaded!');
    }
}

window.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
    if (event.data.isAppLoaded) {
        console.log('React app successfully loaded!');
    }
}
```

**Background.js**

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, info) {
    if (info.status === 'complete') {
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {isPageLoaded: true});
        })
    }
})
```

On some websites the page loads first then the React-app and vice-versa on some other websites. This becomes more complicated with websites that have lots of embedded iframes such as LinkedIn.

What is the correct/better way to guarantee the React-app AND the page has finished loading?

*Please ignore the wildcard message passing. I'm aware of its security vulnerabilities. Above code snippets are simplified version of what I have.*

Comment: Both your iframe and your content script can report their onload completeness to your background script which will have a `Map` of tabId mapped to {pageLoaded, appLoaded} objects so it can send another message to your content script and to your iframe when both booleans are set.

Comment: Too many thoughts without seeing [MCVE](/help/mcve).